# Drupal content body articles disappeared

Tags: drupal

I am using drupal and my body content articles is disappeared. 
I can see it only if I try editing it.
Can you help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Drupal 7, make sure you are printing

```
<?php print render($content); ?>
```

in your node.tpl.php file

Also, make sure your node is set to published.

Comment: the problem is that the plain text is not set as default. If I edit every article and put plain text I can see the content. How can i solve it ? Thanks

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem! Another problem is that in the editor I see only html codes

Comment: which editor are you using? I suggest the ckeditor module if you aren't already using it.